# PL / Sql Query to store array of variables

Tags: oracle

Input variable `(Variable1,variable2)`.

```
Variable1=Mobile
Variable2=1:0,2:1,3:0
```

I want to store the above variable into oracle database like below format using the stored procedure:

| Prod_name | Accessories_no | Include |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mobile | 1 | 0 |
| Mobile | 2 | 1 |
| Mobile | 3 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp as follows:

```
insert into your_Table
select Variable1, 
       regexp_substr(regexp_substr(Variable2,'[^,]+', level),'[^:]+',1),
       regexp_substr(regexp_substr(Variable2,'[^,]+', level),'[^:]+',2)
  from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count(Variable2,',') + 1
```

Comment: create or replace procedure Megatovin(i_Variable1 IN Varchar2,i_Variable2 Varchar2)
AS
variable1 varchar2; 
Variable2 varchar2;
Begin
Variable1=i_Variable1;
Variable2=i_Variable2;

insert into mega
select Variable1, 
       regexp_substr(regexp_substr(Variable2,'[^,]+', level),'[^:]+',1),
       regexp_substr(regexp_substr(Variable2,'[^,]+', level),'[^:]+',2)
  from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count(Variable2,',') + 1

end;

Thanks for your response.Tried the above logic still facing error.

Answer (score 0):

You could write simple split-replace logic in your procedure like below:

```
declare
Variable1 varchar2(10) := 'Mobile';
Variable2 varchar2(100) := '1:0,2:1,3:0';
temp varchar2(10) := '';
col1 varchar2(10) := '';
col2 varchar2(10) := '';
begin
while length(Variable2) > 0 loop
    --split by comma
    if instr(Variable2, ',') > 0 then
        temp := substr(Variable2, 0, instr(Variable2, ','))
    else
       temp := substr(Variable2, 0, length(Variable2));
    end if;
    
    --remove the 1st set
    Variable2 := replace(Variable2, temp,'');
    
    --split by colon and get the values
    col1 := substr(temp, 0, instr(temp, ':')-1);
    col2 := substr(temp, instr(temp, ':')+1, length(temp));
    
    insert into my_table values(Variable1, col1, col2);
end loop;
exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
```